# CSS Columns: Fixed width and "remainder"?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I want to have two columns. The right one is 200px wide, and the left one just takes up the remaining width. Is this possible? What do I set the width of the left column to be?

Comment: Are you using a `<table>` or `<div>`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442412/how-to-position-two-div-elements-side-by-side

Comment: @gmcalab: `<div>`. Tables don't give you attitude, but the purists would eat me alive.

Comment: @Ryan: Not quite the same. He wants 2 fluid columns. Interesting though!

Comment: @Mark - It's the same concept, just with one fixed and one fluid. Just fix the width of the right column and float it to the right.

Comment: @Mark, yea I would never recommend using table for your layout but it wasn't specific in the question, I read it first as a data table. But then as I was about to answer I thought you might have meant using `<div>` ... so before I answered I wanted to clarify...

Comment: @Ryan: You're right... that solution actually does work better.

Comment: @Ryan: Actually, I lied. It works well when the left column has a fixed width, but not when the right column has a fixed width http://jsfiddle.net/E4tnM/ the left column won't push the right column out

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## Update: Solved Using Flexbox

Now that we have [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (with [over 95% support globally](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)) this layout (and others) can be easily achieved without styles being dependent on source order.

*Flexbox Example:*

#### HTML

```
<div class="flex-container">
   <div class="flex-column"> Big </div>
   <div class="fixed-column"> Small </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.flex-container {
   display: flex;
}
.flex-column {
   flex: 1;
}

.fixed-column {
  width: 200px;
}
```

#### [Live Demo using Flexbox](http://jsfiddle.net/2886s5ec/)

---

---

---

## Solved Using Floats

The trick is matching the remainder column’s margin to the floated sidebar’s width. Remember, source order matters when using floats, so we make sure the floated element comes first.

*Example right-aligned small column:*

#### HTML

```
<div id="Container">
    <div id="RightColumn">Right column</div>
    <div id="LeftColumn">Left column</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#RightColumn {
    float : right;
    width : 200px;
}

#LeftColumn {
    margin-right : 200px;
}​
```

#### Live Demo

- [Right-aligned small column](http://jsfiddle.net/bgBXM/23/)
- [Left-aligned small column](http://jsfiddle.net/bgBXM/10/)

Comment: Could there be a solution that the order of the HTML code is `LeftColumn` then `RightColumn` (where the right column is fixed)?

Comment: @ton I’ve updated my answer with a Flexbox solution.

Comment: Flexbox solution doesn't work when inline content is added to the 'remainder' column - it then just keeps expanding.

Answer (score 7):

You `float` the left column and set margin to minimum of the width of the left column.

```
<div id="Container">
    <div id="LeftColumn" style="float: left; margin-right: 200px;"></div>
    <div id="RightColumn" style="float: right; width: 200px;"></div>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div id="Container">
    <div id="RightColumn" style="float: right; width: 200px;"></div>
    <div id="LeftColumn" style="margin-right: 200px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you did it backwards to how I posted it... surely you mean to give the right column the fixed width and the left one the margin?

Comment: Actually, you broke it ;) The right column is nudged down below the left now. Adding `float:left` to the left col too seems to fix the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/4k9Fj/

Comment: Check your link, and my update. You can use the same code but switch the order of columns in HTML. My mistake.

Comment: Actually, none of these solutions work really well w/ a background http://jsfiddle.net/bgBXM/
I need the div to actually expand to take up the full space.

Comment: And when you add more content http://jsfiddle.net/P6YWr/ it just doesn't work at all

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to float divs, you can do the following:

```
.rightDiv {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
}

.mainDiv {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I don't mind floats actually. I think you need to wrap these columns in a container that has `position:relative` in order to have the columns relative to the container, rather than the page, no?

Comment: @Mark: You don't have to have the columns in a container unless you want to limit the overall width of the page (i.e., not let it expand and contract with the width of the browser).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Set the right column's style to float: right and width: 200px, and the left column will be the content and take up the rest of the width.

Comment: Don't forget to set the margin of the right part to 200px to, otherwise your text will get under the left column if it's shorter.