# Creating a Two-Column HTML Page with Collage of Images

Tags: html, css

I have a collage of images that are placed on a page at a specific location, i.e. `position: absolute`. Right now, my code looks something like this:

```
<body>
<div class='im1' style="..."></div>
<div class='im2' style="..."></div>
<div class='im3' style="..."></div>
<div class='im4' style="..."></div>
...
</body>
```

where `style` contains the `left:__px` `top:__px` (some values). The size of the collage is also variable size. My question is that if I want to create a two column page, i.e. have a sidebar on either the right/left side of the page with the collage on the other side, how would I do that?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_two_columns.asp check this out. you can use `display: flex` or `display: grid`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a stable two column layout in HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573855/how-to-make-a-stable-two-column-layout-in-html-css)